# Combinatorics - Contest Problem. Seeking a mathematical enhancement of my solution.

Tags: combinatorics

A group of friends, numbered 1, 2, 3, . . . , 16, take turns picking random numbers. Person 1 picks a number uniformly (at random) in [0, 1], then person 2 picks a number uniformly (at random) in [0, 2], and so on, with person k picking a number uniformly (at random) in [0, k]. What is the probability that the 16 numbers picked are strictly increasing?

This problem appeared as the last question on Harvard MIT Math tournament.  I had not heard of a thing called parking function before I attempted to solve it.  While trying to solve it using tools that I know, I came to an interesting observation and which in turn works for all n.  I am not a pure mathematician and I am wondering if this relates to the volume of a polytope representing a parking function.

The original solution is posted here in http://hmmt.mit.edu/static/archive/february/solutions/2015/combo.pdf.

Thus for n friends, the answer seems to be $\frac{(n+1)^{(n-1)}}{(n!)^2}$.

For n = 2, my limited knowledge of statistics says that it should be equal to

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x_1}^{2}\frac{1}{2}dx_2dx_1 = \frac{3}{4} $$

Applying the formula for parking function definition, I get $\frac{3^1}{(2!)^2}$

For n = 3,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x_1}^{2}\int_{x_2}^{3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}dx_3dx_2dx_1 = \frac{4}{9}  = \frac{4^2}{(3!)^2}$$

For n = 4, This is where I am letting my imagination go wild.  I tried this it seems to work for n=4, n=5  and others.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x_1}^{2}\int_{x_2}^{3}\int_{x_3}^{4}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}dx_4dx_3dx_2dx_1 = \frac{125}{24*24}  = \frac{5^3}{(4!)^2}$$ and so on.

I did not try n = 16 but it should work. the solution for n = 16

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x_1}^{2}\int_{x_2}^{3}\cdots \int_{x_{15}}^{16}\frac{1}{16!}dx_{16}\cdots dx_4dx_3dx_2dx_1 = = \frac{17^{15}}{({16}!)^2}$$ .  Is this right to proceed this way and if so what would a mathematician call this?

I wish someone could give some perspective.